# How do I make an asp.net page submit to a specific IP address?

Tags: asp.net

How do I make an asp.net page submit to a specific IP address?

Every time the page submits (during postback) I wish to have it submit to a specific IP address? Is that possible in .net 3.5?

Comment: Could you explain it a little more? Do you mean that if visitor #1 makes a postback visitor #2 sees it?

Comment: we have 2 web servers, and a domain lister. Our session doesn't work properly - and i am not sure that this will be fixed anytime soon. So, my solution was to find out during the first postback what server we are connecting to and encode all the links/buttons on that particular IP. That, until I realized that page submit might not work with this solution. That's what I am trying to do in a nutshell

Comment: i realize that this is an awkward solution, but at this point that's the only one I have - as it has been decided to code in .net but w/o properly functioning session. angry me can't do much.

Answer (score 1):

In Asp.Net 3.5 (you must have Visual Studio SP1 installed) you can set the Form's action in the code behind page by using form.Action = 172.21.151.203

Please note that this will only work with the web application model and not on the web site model.

Comment: except that I get ViewState error.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/970459

so I am not quite sure why they MS implemented this feature (enabling devs to submit to a different page); since there is no use for it; and it's listed not to work. MS never seems to amaze me in a bad way - all this money and still stupid stupid dev tools.

Answer (score 1):

[How to: Post ASP.NET Web Pages to a Different Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178140.aspx)

```
<asp:Button 
  ID="Button1" 
  PostBackUrl="~/TargetPage.aspx"
  runat="server"
  Text="Submit" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are relying on the user to interact with a Button for postback operations, then use the [Button.PosbackUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178140(VS.100).aspx) property. You can specify a completely different host.

Comment: TreeView doesn't seem to have this property. Any ideas how i can make sure that any postbacks on TreeView are posted to a specific url/ip?

Comment: For that specific scenario I can only suggest koosk's answer posted in this same thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602847/how-do-i-make-an-asp-net-page-submit-to-a-specific-ip-address/1602915#1602915